# Javascript How to resize div's with data value

Tags: javascript, html, css, dataset

How to resize div's using data-size value? 
The div's should increase size on mouseover (and should show its id value in span) and should return to normal size on mouseout.

Please explain it to me step by step (not with code) ;)

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box_1" data-size=200></div>
<div class="box" id="box_2" data-size=400></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it work using anchor tags.

Please follow the steps below.

1. Create a div with in the anchor tag

```html
<a href="#"><div class="box" id="">Your code</div></a>
```

2. Write styles for 'box' class for a hover and a visited, to increase the size of the div.
3. Remove the mouse cursor when you focus on div by using cursor styles.

Let me know, if you have any challenges to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

1. You create an event listen for mousemove on desired div.
2. You get the data using getAttribute('data-size')
3. You set the width using Javascript
4. When mouseout, you set the width back to its original value using getAttribute.